# jQuery and Wordpress - Scripts not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Im trying to implement some jquery to a wp plugin I am creating.

In the functions.php of my theme I have the following code:

```
function load_jquery() {

    // only use this method is we're not in wp-admin
    if ( !is_admin() ) {

        // deregister the original version of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui-slider');
        wp_deregister_style('jquery-ui-style');


        // discover the correct protocol to use
        $protocol='http:';
        if($_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on') {
            $protocol='https:';
        }

        // register the Google CDN version
        wp_register_script('jquery', $protocol.'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.10.2');
        wp_register_script('jquery-ui-slider', $protocol.'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js', false, '1.10.3');
        wp_register_style('jquery-ui-style', $protocol.'//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', false );

        // add it back into the queue
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider');
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-style');
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_jquery');
```

Then in one of the plugin files I output the following via a function and add_action('wp_head', 'functions_name');

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(function($) {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
</script>';
```

Still nothing works, even though I can see the jquery loaded before the actual script.

Any ideas? It works if I skip the wp_enqueue_script part and past everything inside the header.php of the themefile.

Comment: What is the problem? The script isn't loaded at all, or it's loaded but not working?

Comment: The script is loaded, so that I can see them in the source code, but they won't work

Comment: I'm running the Genesis framework btw.

Comment: instead of `echo` you could use `?>...<?`, then also the syntax highlighters do their work for html and javascript

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you link to a live page?

Comment: No Im developing locally. I tried to step out of php as well but not working anyway. Does anyone know if there are any known issues with Genesis framework and jquery?

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap your script with `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` because the jquery object may be loaded but you need the jquery-ui scripts as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
</script>';
```

Comment: I tried that as well but still no results. I am pretty sure it has something to do with Genesis framework.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem is the wordpress **conflict** situation in order for your script to work you need to replace all **'$'** signs you use in your jQuery with   ' jQuery ' . 
Every good wordpress theme dev knows this , wordpress conflicts with your code so you need to adapt .

**Example :**

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider({ 
            etc etc 
        )};
       )};
```

I hope i m right because i had the same issue , did that and it was solved . :)