# How to load dynamic content (get, html, data) via jquery/css in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to re-edit my website, and convert it's content into wordpress. I have the layer slider in which I've selected `<div/video>` option to add a NowPlaying html div which is loaded dynamically via jquery from an external file on my dropbox.

I'm using this function to load the external file into my webpage:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27854284/Stuff/Music/Now.Playing.Winamp/nowPlaying_test.html", function(data) {
        $("#nowPlayingInfo").html(data);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I've copied the following two javascript helper files, required for this content. I've copied these two lines into the header of my theme...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo TMM_THEME_URI ?>/js/date.extensions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo TMM_THEME_URI ?>/js/date.to_relative_time.jquery.js"></script>
```

And this is the div that's supposed to be replaced with the dropbox file..:

```
<div style="">
<p style=""><span style="">Now Playing </span><span style="">Winamp Update: <span class="rel_" id="now_playing_txt">0 minutes ago!</span></span></p>
<p><span id="nowPlayingInfo">Artist - Song Title</span></p>
</div>
```

The dropbox file contains some text based code and html data:

```
<script>
date/time functions
</script>

<script>
shuffle enabled/disabled text changer with jquery .text function: ("#shuffle_s").text("Enabled");
</script>

<span>
nowplaying content here...
</span>
```

That's mostly all... This works perfectly on this html based version, but does not function on the wordpress... I'm using xampp with localhost url for my wordpress...

Please could someone suggest method to load this content into wordpress? Thanks!

EDIT:

The text is appearing correctly, but the "relative-time-helpers" aren't showing the time correctly". The time helpers consist two scripts: as already mentioned above: 
`date.extensions.js` and `date.to_relative_time.jquery.js`.

Here are the scripts source:
**date.extensions.js**

```
/*
 * Returns a description of this past date in relative terms.
 * Example: '3 years ago'
 */
Date.prototype.toRelativeTime = function() {
  var delta       = new Date() - this;
  var units       = null;
  var conversions = {
    millisecond: 1, // ms    -> ms
    second: 1000,   // ms    -> sec
    minute: 60,     // sec   -> min
    hour:   60,     // min   -> hour
    day:    24,     // hour  -> day
    month:  30,     // day   -> month (roughly)
    year:   12      // month -> year
  };

  for(var key in conversions) {
    if(delta < conversions[key]) {
      break;
    } else {
      units = key; // keeps track of the selected key over the iteration
      delta = delta / conversions[key];
    }
  }

  // pluralize a unit when the difference is greater than 1.
  delta = Math.floor(delta);
  if(delta !== 1) { units += "s"; }
  return [delta, units, "ago"].join(" ");
};

/*
 * Wraps up a common pattern used with this plugin whereby you take a String 
 * representation of a Date, and want back a date object.
 */
Date.fromString = function(str) {
  return new Date(Date.parse(str));
};
```

**date.to_relative_time.jquery.js**

```
(function($) {
    /*
     * A handy jQuery wrapper for converting tags with JavaScript parse()-able
     * time-stamps into relative time strings.
     *
     * Usage:
     *   Suppose numerous Date.parse()-able time-stamps are available in the 
     *   inner-HTML of some <span class="rel"> elements...
     *
     *   $("span.rel").toRelativeTime()
     *
     * Examples: '5 years ago', '45 minutes ago'
     *
     * Requires date.extensions.js to be loaded first.
     */
    $.fn.toRelativeTime = function() {
      this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text(Date.fromString($this.html()).toRelativeTime());
      });
    };
  })(jQuery);
```

I only tried to change the `date.to_relative_time.js` file, but it still didn't show up with the correct formet. It should show something like "5 minutes ago" or "3 hours ago", but it just shows a different time format: `Tue Feb 04 2014 13:10:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wordpress `$` [may not refer](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-is-not-working-in-wordpress-solution/) to [the jQuery library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173946/jquery-and-wordpress-scripts-not-working)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.get("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27854284/Stuff/Music/Now.Playing.Winamp/nowPlaying_test.html", function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        $("#nowPlayingInfo").html(data);
    });
});
```

In the loaded html

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var now = new Date(); //"now"
    var play_Time = new Date("2014/02/03 15:49:49"); // some date
    var diff = Math.abs(now - play_Time);
    var diff_minutes = Math.round(diff / (1000 * 60));
    $("#now_playing_txt").text(new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes() - diff_minutes).toString());

    $("span.rel_").toRelativeTime();
});
jQuery(function ($) {
    var on_off = "off";
    if (on_off == "on") $("#shuffle_s").text("Enabled");
    else $("#shuffle_s").text("Disabled");
});
```

Comment: **From Chome's Console**: `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`

_....contents of the .html file from dropbox..._

`Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`

Comment: thanks!! Your edited `loaded html` functions perfectly!
But that only works on the layer slider (with div)... doesn't work on the wordpress page... but I only needed to show it on the layer slider anyways... thanks!

Comment: Hi! The text is appearing correctly, but the "relative-time-helpers" aren't showing the time correctly. The time helpers consist two scripts: as already mentioned above: `date.extensions.js` and `date.to_relative_time.jquery.js` ... I've edited the question with the source code of the two scripts... Could you provide any further help? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm displaying it via iframe now... couldn't get it to function properly... iframes are functioning perfectly! Thanks anyways!